# Is it possible to point a domain address to IP and subdomains to another IP?

Tags: dns, ip

Is it possible to point the domain address to one place and the subdomains to another place?

For example:

```
mydomain.net -> 183.85.56.74
stuff.mydomain.net -> 174.24.75.1/~place/
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although, to do it, it might vary because there are so many different domain providers. You just need to add `A Records` to the domain `DNS settings`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can point any level of domain to any IP address.

```
mydomain.net -> 183.85.56.74
stuff.mydomain.net -> 174.24.75.1
stuff2.mydomain.net -> 174.88.99.1
more.stuff2.mydomain.net -> 199.22.33.1
```

However, you cannot point to a folder like

```
174.24.75.1/~place/
```

DNS will only map names to IP address, and knows nothing of webservers or folders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can all be modified by whoever does DNS management for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

For the way you are looking to run things, it's not really a DNS issue(@Paul got it right):

- DNS will only resolve a name (example.com) to an IP address or another name. It doesn't do anything with ports or directing to a specific part of a web server.
- Apache / IIS / whatever web server you use reads host names when the user requests a page, and gives the browser the page that is correct for the URI it's requesting.

You can use a DNS service like [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com), which will do the web redirection for you, but using your web server is better.

- [Apache - Configure Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html)
- [IIS](http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/)